# xxx.cmi is not a compiled interface for this version of OCaml

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, ocaml

There is two files a.cmo and a.cmi which are compiled by ocaml 4.13.1.

I write a file test.ml which only contains one line code: `open A`

Now, I want to use command: `ocamlc -o test.exe a.cmo test.ml` to compile the test.ml in the ocaml 4.14.0 environment(cygwin), and I got an error: `a.cmi is not a compiled interface for this version of OCaml`, I know this error is caused by ocaml version.But I want to know :

Is there any way to compile to get the a.cmo and a.cmi file independent of the ocaml version? In other words, how can I compile the test.ml file linked with a.cmo file and don't need to consider who uses which ocaml version to compile to get this a.cmo?

Does such a method exist? Or do I have to change the version of ocaml?

Answer (score 3):

The compiled artifacts of the OCaml compiler are versioned to avoid consistency issues and cross-version bugs. By design, there is no way around this security net.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if the a.ml includes many useful functions, I want to compile it to be used with "open A" in other ocaml file, just like the ocaml standard library (String List Char.....), how should I do? The .cmi file is necessary?

Comment: You can read a tutorial on compiling OCaml projects (https://ocaml.org/docs/compiling-ocaml-projects). The brief answer is to install dune and let it take care of your compilation woes (https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick-start.html).