# ocamlopt : Error: The file test.cmxa is not a compilation unit description

Tags: compilation, ocaml

I'm new learner to ocaml, so this problem may be a little stupid.

The environment is Cygwin.The ocaml version is ocaml 4.14.0

when I excute the command:`ocamlopt -I tool -o test.exe test.cmxa test.ml` , the error showed:`The file test.cmxa is not a compilation unit description`

the test.ml file contains only one line code:`open T1`

the test.cmxa is compiled with other two file <t1.ml> and <t2.ml>. the tool directory has the middle file:<t1.cmi><t1.cmx><t1.obj><t2.cmi><t2.cmx><t2.obj>, probably the .cmx files is not needed, I'm not sure, so I add all of them into tool directory.

if I execute the command:`ocamlopt -I tool -o test.exe tool/t1.cmx test.ml`, this command can be excuted successfully.

So I want to know if I missed any files or the command is wrong.And anyone can recommend me some tutorial or article to me about how to create and use .cmxa file.(I've read the official tutorial https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/native.html#sec315 , but I still feel confused.)

Comment: There were some useful links in response to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949917/xxx-cmi-is-not-a-compiled-interface-for-this-version-of-ocaml).

Comment: You don't say how you generated test.cmxa. Is there a tool/test.cmxa file? If not, that is your problem. (Note: I don't use Cygwin, I'm assuming it's close to Linux behavior.)

Comment: Jeffrey, thank you for your response. I'm sure the test.cmxa exist in the root directory and yes Cygwin is close to Linux. Is it possible for other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, my best guess is that you forgot the `-a` flag when building the library archive:

```
ocamlopt -a -o test.cmxa t1.cmx t2.cmx
```

I would advise you to first learn how to use dune which would take care of all those details and more before (potentially) diving in the subtleties of the compiler CLI.